# Create a database for each site created in multisite?

Tags: multisite, database

I am running a multisite network and I want to be able have each new subsite to have it's own database instead of 1 big database. Is there a way to make it whenever I create a new subsite it should also create a new database?

Comment: Have you tried Google? I found several threads with a similar question, ie. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104450/wordpress-multisite-multi-database.